# Publishing website using apache tomacat 6.0

Tags: tomcat

I have a project build using servlet,jsp and postgres as backend. I want to publish this project as website. I have registered a site but I can only use host redirect to request the site. But I want my index page to be open when type the site address without directing to localhost port. I want to use AA or CNAME but not url redirect.

I have installed apache in 8085 port. I dont want to show my ipaddress in address bar when user request my site. 
  please help me i have worked hard to build this project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to change the tomcat default port to 80 instead of 8085. I assume you're running Linux. I'm only expirienced with Ubuntu, so the directories may not be the same. In the /var/etc/tomcat6 folder should be a file called server.xml. There, you have to change the port number. Also, you need run Tomcat as root. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do that.